# Mixing contenteditable OR Markdown and EJS

Tags: javascript, markdown, ejs, contenteditable

In my app, I need to make it possible for users to be able to write EJS-based templates. Asking them to write HTML is a little too much.

So, the idea is to allow them to write their templates using either contenteditable OR markdown, and mix contents. The problem is obvious:

- `contenteditable` will *always* add `<div>` to each line, even in the EJS section of the site, hence ruining it
- `Markdown` has the same problem

How would you tackle this problem? (that is, semi-visual writing of programmable templates)

Comment: Why do *users* need the ability to write program templates?  What are you trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: I want to achieve the functionality of users being able to write their own templates...

Comment: Guess I don't see the utility in having users write templates (a custom CMS?).